# Using .load() to bring in full HTML including <!DOCTYPE> etc

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using .load() to bring in content from an external HTML file - however i'd like to bring in everything from the external HTML. This includes everything from the !DOCTYPE onwards.

I'm building a template builder of sorts that allows the user to export an HTML file at the end of the process so the DOCTYPE and everything in head is required.

Here's the script I'm using currently:

```
    $('.addNewContent').click(function(e) {
    $( "#content" ).load( "external-file.html" );
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Do I need to include something else to get this to work? Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Having two DOCTYPE for the same document cannot be a good idea, what about using an iframe?

Comment: Try using `$.ajax()` instead, so you can parse the response data, rather than just push it into an element.

Comment: Is a cross-domain request? Not work for jQuery.load